# Retrieve google contact based on contact Id

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

When I issue a contacts request to get all of a user's contacts  I get contacts Id's of the form:

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sometestaccount%40gmail.com/base/4f822c758a541b6b
```

Reading the google contacts api 3.0 I was a bit confused on what uri should I use to delete a contact.
Doing:

```
var cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
var uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sometestaccount%40gmail.com/base/4f822c758a541b6b");
var contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(uri);
cr.Delete(contact);
```

fails with

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException : Execution of request returned unexpected result: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/sometestaccount%40gmail.com/base/4f822c758a541b6b?max-results=50MovedPermanently
```

What's the correct way to get a contact Id and request for a contact deletion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this and I found 2 errors.

1) I got a "Moved permanently because I issued my request in http and I should have done that in https.

2) The uri format is strictly :

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}
```

I had a `setting.Pagesize = 50` , which caused my uri to be

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}?max-results=50
```

which is invalid and returns a 400 bad request.

The contact Id is the hash code that you get from the contact.Id result uri. After you retrieve the contact entry, the deletion is as documented in the google api contacts v3.0 .