# How to retrieve a single contact with gdata? Getting a 'not supported' error

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm copying the code here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact.

And here's my code:

```
Dim cr = ContactAuthentication()
Dim groups = GetGroups(cr)
Dim entry As Contact
entry = cr.Retrieve(Of Contact)(New Uri("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/38B2D4F80D96B2C2"))
```

On the last line, it falls with the following error:

> Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: 'Execution of request
>   failed:
>   https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/38B2D4F80D96B2C2?max-results=100'
>
> "The 'max-results' parameter is not supported on this
>   resource"

Which is odd, since I never put in a max result parameter. Also, if it makes any difference, the Google docs show an example that takes a string url as the param for `Retrieve`. I could not find such an overload, the closest is what I put here, using a `Uri`

Anyone have any ideas how I can retrieve a single contact by id for updating?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this [documentation: Retrieving a single contact](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact). To retrieve a single contact, send an authorized GET request to the contact's selfLink URL:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}
```

With the appropriate values in place of `userEmail` and `contactID`. Be noted that the special `userEmail` value default can be used to refer to the authenticated user.

**And as referred with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697026/retrieve-google-contact-based-on-contact-id), maybe you had `setting.Pagesize = 100`, which caused your uri to be `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}?max-results=100`.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: yup. my "contactsauthentication" was setting the pagesize. thanks for giving me the lead :-)